# Fluid grid layout with fixed pixel spacing

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

In the following attempt at a "fluid" grid layout with fixed spacing between cells, can anyone explain why the spacing above the bottom left image differs when the container width changes. Examples follow.

**Questions:**

- Why does this happen? What didn't I account for?
- **or**/and can you suggest a better way of implementing such a grid with CSS? The pictures must keep proportions, and it should work with IE8.

Available at [this jsFille](http://jsfiddle.net/ePPaq/).

*With ~200px width:*
[image: width ~200px]

*And ~1120px width (cropped):*
[image: width ~1120px]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/></div>
    <div class="col2"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/></div>
    <div class="col3">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/285/678"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col4"><img src="http://placekitten.com/875/532"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{    
    outline: 2px solid #000;
    margin: 30px auto;

    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 0;
    position: relative;

    padding-left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
}

.col1, .col2, .col3{
    width: 37.5%;
    float: left;
}

.col1{
    margin-left: -20px;
}
.col1, .col2{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.col3{
    width: 25%;
}
.col3 img:first-child{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col4{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 75%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bottom left image is positioned absolute at bottom:0; left:0;, so the spacing between it and the pictures above it depend ONLY on the aspect ratio of that bottom left image.  In other words, if you want to reduce that space, you need to increase the height of that image.

Comment: No, not only. It also depends on the aspect ratio of the images that "decide" the height of the container and the spacing between them. So this doesn't answer anything afais.

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't have any absolute positioning here.  I don't normally advocate for tables, but maybe a table layout would give you better results here.  Then you can just set the cellspacing.

Comment: *"the spacing between it and the pictures above it depend ONLY on the aspect ratio of that bottom left image"*, can you illustrate this by changing the aspect ratio of that picture so that the spacing always stays the same? If not then the statement is false (in yet another regard).  Tables may work, but I'm not 100% sure about that any more. Maybe something doesn't add up here, that's why we get differences.

Comment: I think your problem is that the aspect ratio of your entire grid changes as you resize the window, because you set fixed 10px spacing between images.  You would need to make that spacing fluid as well, in order to preserve a certain aspect ratio.  Try setting the spacing to 0 and make the grid line up, then I think you will see that it stays consistent as you resize.